# Unity restart script not activating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a sort of parkour game in unity and I'm trying to make it where if you fall off the platfrom, the level restarts. I'm using unity 2020.1.3, here my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Restart : MonoBehaviour
{

private Scene scene;


void Start()
{
    scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(scene.name);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
}
```

Whenever I run my scene, I fall off the platform and nothing happens. I'm not that experienced in unity and I have no clue whats going on. The script is assigned to a cube expanded throughout the level, and is supposed to trigger when the player collides with it

Comment: Are you sure the trigger is fired?

Comment: I dont know. How am I able to check that and if it doesn't what do i do to fix?

Comment: Put in some logging

Answer (score 0):

Does your cube have a rigidbody attached?

Also, tick isTrigger.

Here is an outline:

https://www.binpress.com/unity-3d-collisions-basics/

Comment: On StackOverflow we avoid just linking to answers, give a brief description of what the page contains here in the answer. Also this doesn't seem like a full answer and may have been beter suited as just a comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that above objects has Colliders and at least one has Rigidbody.
Second of all, replace your OnTriggerEnter for this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(scene.name);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

With "gameobject.tag", you were comparing that object with itself. If you want to compare if the name of the object that collides (Collider name) is equals something, you need to use the name of the parameter of Collider class. In you case, is "other". By the way, `other.tag == "name"` is deprecated, use `other.CompareTag("something")`

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand that (I'm sorry i'm really new and I need someone holding my hand throughout all this) can you be a litttlee more specific? I added colliders and rigidbodies to both my player and the cube, nothing seeming to be happening.

Comment: You are calling the object that you want to see if collides as "other" on parameter OnTriggerEnter(Collision other). So, if you want to get the object that is colliding, you should do "other.something" not gameobject.something. "gameobject" is the same thing as "this". Also, you are using OnTriggerEnter, so you have to check "isTrigger" on one rigidbody. Tip: Trigger is just to see collisions, the object doesn't "become a wall" at all. If you want to check normal collision use OnCollisionEnter instead OnTriggerEnter.